# Numeric value is not recognized error in OPENQUERY

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, openquery

I have the following stored procedure. When it runs, i get the error
returned message "Numeric value '+@requestno+' is not recognized" . I believe the setting of the variable requestno is not working. How do i resolve it?

```
Declare @requestno nvarchar(max)
Set @requestno = (Select requestno from table1 where condition met)
SELECT * INTO tempdb..#temptable FROM OPENQUERY (SalesDb,
    'SELECT  * 
      FROM   TableinAnotherDb
      WHERE  1=1     
     and request_number=''+@requestno+'' Order by some column'    
  )
```

Thank you

Comment: I think we cannot pass user defined variables to the openquery.

Answer (score 0):

prepare you query in advance:

```
Declare @queryStr nvarchar(max)
SELECT @queryStr ='SELECT  * 
      FROM   TableinAnotherDb
      WHERE  1=1     
     and request_number='+ requestno+' Order by some column'   
FROM table1 
WHERE condition met
SELECT * INTO tempdb..#temptable FROM OPENQUERY (SalesDb,@queryStr)
```